# Further Command line arguments from c# to an external exe

Tags: c#-2.0, console-application

I'm running an external exe from a C# windows application. The exe is an console window and i pass initial command line arguments "a and b" like this

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "something.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "a b";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
p.Close();
```

Now i need to pass the second arguments in the same exe that is the application "something.exe" starts execution with the initial arguments a and b and then it further needs some inputs c and d in the next step. How can i give the second input c and d in the C# application. Please provide me a solution.

Comment: Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "something.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "a b";

    **p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;**

    p.Start();
      
    **p.StandardInput.WriteLine("c");
    p.StandardInput.WriteLine("d");**
    
    p.WaitForExit();
    p.Close();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it guys

```
Process p = new Process();     
p.StartInfo.FileName = "something.exe"; 
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "a b"; 

**p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;**    
**p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;**

p.Start(); 

**p.StandardInput.WriteLine("c");** 
**p.StandardInput.WriteLine("d");**

p.WaitForExit(); 
p.Close();
```